# How to set back activity to Fragment classes?

Tags: java, android, performance, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I am developing an Android Application with navigation activity and there are some list of options in navigation drawer and my First page is also in this activity. I am navigating to another page through the options present in the navigation drawer which are Fragment classes. I need to come back to the first page if I press back button on device. But it goes to pages which I visited before. My Target is to come back to First page from the respective Fragment class.

At times when I hit back button, it also comes to my splash screen, Kindly help me to fix this. Thanks in advance. 
This is the code of my FirstPage from where I am navigating to another pages through drawer. I need to come back to this same page again from the drawer (FirsPage)

```
public void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
    switch(menuItem.getItemId()) {

        //1.User Profile

        case R.id.navigation_item_attachment:
            fragmentClass = ProfileTab.class;
         //   finish();

            break;

        //2.FeedBack


        //case R.id.navigation_item_images:
           /* fragmentClass = SearchHistoryTab.class;
            break;*/

        case R.id.navigation_refer:
           fragmentClass = ReferFrndz.class;

           // finish();
            break;

        case R.id.navigation_daily:
          fragmentClass = DailyUsage.class;
            break;

        //4.About Us

        case R.id.navigation_about:
           fragmentClass = AboutJc.class;
            break;

        //4.Contact Us

        case R.id.navigation_item_location:
            fragmentClass = ContactJc.class;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    try {

        fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();

    }

    catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.search_layout, fragment).commit();
    menuItem.setChecked(true);
    setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
}
```

I used Finish() but it didn't work. It terminating my entire application.

Splash Screen Code:

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Thread mythread = new Thread() {
                public void run(){
                    try{
                        sleep(3000);
                    }catch(InterruptedException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            finally {
                              ..... 
                    }
            }
        }
    };
    mythread.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your `Fragmenttransaction` code to add `ProfileTab` (FirstPage) in backstack entry.' So you get `ProfileTab` (FirstPage) back after click back button.

```
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        if(fragment.equals(ProfileTab.class)){
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.search_layout, fragment).addToBackStack("fragment_tag").commit();
//Only add backstack entry for first page so you get after click on back button
        }
       else 
        {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.search_layout, fragment).commit();
        }
        menuItem.setChecked(true);
        setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
```

Use this solution and share your feedback with replay will help us to improve solution.

Comment: I tried this, It goes to my splash screen and come to my FirstPage. Since i set 5 seconds for splash screen. What else we can modify to solve this? Any idea?

Comment: can you post splash screen code which help more clear.

Comment: yeah. I posted my splash screen code. Kindly check the updated question

Comment: What is the fragment_tag in addBackstack?

Comment: `fragment_tag` is a tag id string which helps to FragmentManager to find Fragment by tag id.

Comment: You need to `finish()` SplashActivity

Comment: If I give finish() in splash screen and hit back button, app is getting closed. Any idea to fix that?

Comment: Its my sharedpreferences code, navigating to next activity.

Comment: I also like to point that, *****My splash screen is in Mainactivity and my firstpage is not MainActivity. ****

Comment: Should I give any string value in fragment_tag or I should type as it is. How to use that. How to set the string ID to each fragment.  it will be helpful if you post with the code.

Comment: Yes, You replace with your own string with `fragment_tag`

Comment: `FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
     String id="back page";
        if (fragment.equals(ProfileTab.class)) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.search_layout, fragment).addToBackStack(id).commit();`

Should I give like this??